# How to attach event with object for resize & click

Tags: jquery, attachevent

I am using jQuery version 1.4.1. I try to attach resize & click events this way but it is not working.

```
var $els = [];
$els.window = $(window);
$els.window.bind('resize', getNewWindowCorner());
$els.toggleUPSButtons.bind('click', toggleUPSOverlay());
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using   `$els.window.bind('resize', getNewWindowCorner());` function executed immediately,so **remove bracket**

```
$els.window.bind('resize', getNewWindowCorner);
$els.toggleUPSButtons.bind('click', toggleUPSOverlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to give the reference of the function to the handler, not the returned value. Remove the trailing brackets:

```
$els.window.bind('resize', getNewWindowCorner);
$els.toggleUPSButtons.bind('click', toggleUPSOverlay);
```

Answer (score 1):

One different way is as follows if you want to call the functions yourself.

```
var $els = [];
$els.window = $(window);

$els.window.bind('resize', function(){
 getNewWindowCorner();
});

$els.toggleUPSButtons.bind('click', function(){
 toggleUPSOverlay();
});
```